# Which software can write audio CD images in ISO format?

Tags: audio, iso-image, burning, compact-disc

I want to write an audio CD from mp3s I have on my computer.

I want software that lets me select mp3s and outputs an ISO image not on CD writer.

I have NTI CD MAKER, but it writes images in `.ncd` format, not ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Nero](http://www.nero.com) software. I've used it before to create images and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

[Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) is also a good one and the best part it is FREE.